# Issues with tuple as a parameter/argument or return value

Tags: swift, tuples

I am learning Swift3.0 after having a decade of experiences in Objective-C.

While working with tuples, I found it fancy to group many values in one. Once I started comparing it with `struct` of Obj-C.

But while passing it to a function or returning from a function the fanciness becomes a pain in ass!

You can not

1. `return` the whole tuple
2. pass tuple as a single value

In both the cases you have to break it into individual datatypes.

Am I getting it right from the above observations?

Comment: How is this question Objective-C related? Obj-C doesn't have tuples...

Comment: @Hamish: because I compared it with `struct` of Obj-C or `C`.

Comment: But your question (as far as I understand) is not about a comparison between Swift tuples and (Obj-)C structs – it's purely about what you can and can't do with Swift tuples.

Comment: Although I'm not sure what you mean by "You can not return the whole tuple" – you can do `func foo() -> (String, Int) { return ("foo", 5) }` just fine. Regarding your second point, you can also have tuple parameters, e.g `func bar(_ t: (String, Int)) {}` – I *assume* what you're talking about is the inability to do tuple splatting for function parameters, [which is a feature that was removed from the language](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0029-remove-implicit-tuple-splat.md).

Comment: @Hamish: Thanks for helping me out to reach the correct place. It helped me, I am writing the answer, please correct if something  is wrong or more can be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `typealias` so you don't have to use the tuple repeatedly:

```
typealias Complex = (Int, Int)

var complex1 = (2, 4)
var complex2 = (3, 5)

func addComplexNumbers(c1:Complex, c2:Complex) -> Complex {
    let sum = (c1.0 + c2.0, c1.1 + c2.1)
    return sum
}

print("Sum = \(addComplexNumbers(c1:complex1, c2:complex2))")
```

You can also use named parameters in your tuple, if you intend to retrieve the values separately:

```
typealias Complex = (x: Int, y: Int)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the direction provided by Hamish, I got to know binding to a single value called [**"splatting" is purposefully removed**](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0029-remove-implicit-tuple-splat.md). Looks somewhat in between passing four values instead of just two.

However we can use in this following way:

```
//This is an example of Complex number.
// 2+4i adding with 3+5i will become 5+9i

var complex1 = (2, 4)
var complex2 = (3, 5)

func addComplexNumbers(c1:(Int, Int), c2:(Int, Int)) -> (Int, Int){
    let sum = (c1.0+c2.0, c1.1+c2.1)
    return sum
}

print("Sum = \(addComplexNumbers(c1:complex1, c2:complex2))")
```

Comment: @Yasir: Why dont paste it as answer? But Why String it should be the Alias name, isn't?

Comment: Apologies for the Strings; was checking a bit of code to ensure the syntax was correct and ended up using the example types instead of yours! Realised after I posted that this is a bit complex so have submitted an answer with the code.